# Weird pattern combination in Amun Re card game

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

On the board game of [Amun Re: The Card Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/232303/amun-re-card-game/files) there is this rule that asks you to combine a certain number of coin cards until you have a specific amount of money.

For example with Card Coins of (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) you are asked to select a number of cards that total up to a specific amount (something smaller than 40).

Very quickly I got tired of running the combinations on my head on what specific cards I should keep if I had to have a total of, for example, 18 coins (there are 14 possible sets) so I wrote a small script to generate all possible combinations until a total sum of 40 (actually you cannot reach sums larger than 36, since you do not have that many card coins)

This resulted to this [table](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WS7Fy0-rTYmX0SxhNddiAzxT8TwECJswVd8TLvtg7rM/edit?usp=sharing).

By looking at the combination of cards, I wondered "which card appears more often in these, seemingly, random sets"?

After changes to my script to count the number of occurrences I found something surprising:

```
{0: 255, 1: 128, 2: 128, 3: 128, 4: 128, 5: 128, 6: 128, 7: 128, 8: 128}
```

I would have **never** thought that the number of occurrences is the same for **every** card (well, except 0 that appears in all sets).

Running the same, for different initial card coins, I found the exact same pattern:

For sequences of cards running up to 9:

```
{0: 511, 1: 256, 2: 256, 3: 256, 4: 256, 5: 256, 6: 256, 7: 256, 8: 256, 9: 256}
```

For up to 10:

```
{0: 1023, 1: 512, 2: 512, 3: 512, 4: 512, 5: 512, 6: 512, 7: 512, 8: 512, 9: 512, 10: 512}
```

etc

How can that be? What is the underlying principle that "forces" each card to appear the same number of times?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you just counting the number of subsets of a set of order $n$ that contain a particular element?  But that's just $2^{n-1}$.  Are you counting something else?

Comment: I am counting how many times the number X appears in the provided sets of numbers.  My initial assumption was that smaller numbers would appear more often, but I was way wrong.

Comment: So, you specify $n$ and a cap on the sum, call it $N$.  But then, of course, it isn't always true that the numbers occur with equal frequency.  For instance, if $N<n$ then the number $n$ can't appear at all.  so, is the claim only meant to hold for sufficiently large $N$ or something like that?

Comment: Of course, if $N≥\frac {n(n+1)}2$ then we are talking about all the subsets, so each element appears exactly $2^{n-1}$ times.  So, what is the relevant range on $N$?

Comment: N **cannot** be arbitrarily large because you do not have enough "coins" to reach that sum. The distribution of the numbers though is surprisingly "equal" that it defies my gut feeling that they should **not** be equal.

Comment: As I wrote, $N≥\frac {n(n+1)}2$ suffices to ensure that each element occurs in exactly $2^{n-1}$ sums.  And if $N$ is small, then the claim is false.  So the question has to be concerned about a particular range of $N$...

Comment: Not sure if I follow along, but these are not some random sets, or all possible sets of randomly combined numbers.  Each set adds up to a specific number.  I do not know if there is room to intuitively get a feel for this, but the results really surprised me.  I guess I was wondering if there was a layman's way of explaining this.